# bit.dev workflow without dedicated team for a shared library and with code review before publishing

Tags: bit.dev

looking for workflow solution. We need something like ad-hoc sharing workflow https://docs.bit.dev/docs/workflows/projects with one addition - before the component publishing could happen only after the code review. let me try to describe the short scenario:

- there is a repo with the shared components
- there are several consumer projects. each one sits in its own repo
- there is no dedicated team to maintain the repo with the shared components
- the developer of consumer project imports a share component and make changes
- the developer wants to create a pull request for a component changes

So far I see only one solution - the developer manually applies changes he made locally to a shared library repo and manually creates a pull request. Kind of boring. Does the bit.dev provide an automated solution for such case?

Comment: get the response in bit.dev slack channel: `yeah… this is something we are working on right now - suggesting changes.`

Answer (score 2):

While a PR-like feature is still not available in Bit, you can use Git's PR workflow to set up a code review process for components with some automation.

> **Note** this flow can work regardless of the specific workflow your team implements. In this answer, I'll focus on the ad-hock flow, as your team uses.

You'll first need to set up automation on your projects, that when there's a change in component's code, your CI will `bit tag && bit export` the modified components. This should happen only when a PR is approved and merged to `master` branch (in Git).
Then using the [Git integration feature](https://blog.bitsrc.io/announcing-auto-github-prs-for-component-version-bumping-74e7768bcd8a) set up your projects to receive PRs on new versions for components.

With these two setups, this will be the workflow your team can utilize:

1. Import component to any project and modify.
2. Submit PR to the project.
3. Have a peer do a code review.
4. When change is merged, run `bit tag && bit export --eject` during CI
5. Commit and push back changes to `package.json` to the repo (with a `skip-ci` flag, per your automation infrastructure).
6. All projects that use that component get a PR from Bit with the newly available version.

I will update this answer whenever a new feature in Bit improves on this workflow.

Answer (score 1):

as Itay says, you can use the [GitHub integration on bit.dev](https://blog.bitsrc.io/announcing-auto-github-prs-for-component-version-bumping-74e7768bcd8a).
But if you want, I create demos projects that show how to use GitHub or Azure CI to integrate the project with Bit, and export new components when code our pushed to master, and also run Bit script on PRs.
https://github.com/teambit/bit-with-github-actions
https://github.com/teambit/bit-with-azure-devops

I hope it will help you.